# Notify user X and Y when they are in the same area

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

I want to add a feature in my app to update X Location value all the time, if Y location value is close to X (let say 25 km) notify both users.

Comment: I added the user location and updated, but i dont know what I should do for the other user to check if they're close to each other. I thought of using MKPolygon.

Comment: Show some code of what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
var distanceInMeters = X.distanceFromLocation(Y)
if distanceInMeter/1000 > 25 {
   // Notify both users here
}
```